# Error while following osmbonuspack "Hello, Routing World!" tutorial

Tags: java, android, navigation, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have created a simple project using OSM.The map is showing up with my current location. Now I want to create a navigation from my current location to a specific point on the map.I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1).

In the **Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, this);** line,I am getting an error like

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from PathOverlay to Polyline
```

I am using the following libraries in the project:

```
1. osmdroid-android-4.1.jar
2. osmbonuspack_3.0.jar
3. slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar
```

Here is the **MainActivity**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.osmdroid.DefaultResourceProxyImpl;
import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.api.Polyline;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.OSRMRoadManager;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.Road;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.RoadManager;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = null;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    // The MapView variable:
    private MapView m_mapView;

    GeoPoint startPoint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         GPSTracker tracker = new GPSTracker(this);
         if (tracker.canGetLocation() == false) {
         tracker.showSettingsAlert();
         } else {
         latitude = tracker.getLatitude();
         longitude = tracker.getLongitude();
         }


          // Find the MapView controller in that layout:
        m_mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        //MapView mapView = new MapView(this, 256); //constructor
        m_mapView.setClickable(true);
        m_mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
           //setContentView(m_mapView); //displaying the MapView
           m_mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
           m_mapView.getController().setZoom(15); //set initial zoom-level, depends on your need
           m_mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude));
           m_mapView.setUseDataConnection(true); 
           m_mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);


           Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_for_map);
             int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
             int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
             marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);

             ResourceProxy resourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(
             getApplicationContext());

             myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker, resourceProxy);
             m_mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);

             GeoPoint myPoint1 = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
             myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint1, "myPoint1", "myPoint1");

             startPoint = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
    }

    //For routing
    public void osmRoute()
    {
        //road manager
        RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager();

        //start and end points
        ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
        waypoints.add(startPoint);
        GeoPoint endPoint = new GeoPoint(48.4, -1.9);
        waypoints.add(endPoint);

        //etreive the road between those points
        Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);

        //build a Polyline with the route shape
        Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, this);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is **activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:enabled="true"      
            android:clickable="true"
        />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Where am I going wrong? What should I do to complete the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to kurtzmarc comment, you are also not using the correct version of OSMBonusPack:

If you are using osmdroid-android-4.1.jar, then you MUST use OSMBonusPack v4.2.6 or above.

Download the latest version (v4.4), not an outdated one.

Comment: Now I am using osmbonuspack_v4.4.jar, this is fine

Comment: @kittu88, where did you get the jar version v4.4 from ? link please?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/#svn%2FBonusPackDownloads%2Farchives

Answer (score 0):

Do you maybe have the wrong Polyline import? Try adding:

```
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Polyline;
```

and get rid of:

```
import org.osmdroid.api.Polyline;
```